# Are there copyrights for board game Risk and can I make the game, or similar, for mobile?

Tags: mobile

are there copyrights for board game Risk? It's popular and with lots of versions floating around, so I don't know if someone has rights or just for specific version. I'm not planning to make money with it, it would be a free game. If not, can I make something similar to that, and how much do I need to change it? I like the game a lot, it's for fun and learning purpose.
Thx in advance :)

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24804/intellectual-rights-to-game-concepts http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58735/how-not-to-break-licence-laws http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/how-closely-can-a-game-resemble-another-game-without-legal-problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Game rules and mechanics cannot be copyrighted. Specific implementations, writings of the rules, names, and associated art CAN be copyrighted.

So if you don't call it Risk, and don't use any of Risk's art, I think you're fine.

The company I work for has had serious problems with dealing with the versions of our games people make for free thinking that alone makes it legal.

But as usual, I say this:

"Getting legal advice from random people on the Internet is not a good idea."

Do your own research, and consult a lawyer if you want to be sure.